# Non-recognized member in lambda expression of EF Core ThenInclude in Extension method

Tags: entity-framework, linq, .net-core, extension-methods

I'm trying to write an extension method to include a certain property (text element, themselves containing a collection of translations) that are present in many of my entity models.

I had no problem with the `.Include` function:

```
public static IIncludableQueryable<T, IEnumerable<Translation>> IncludeTextBitWithTranslations<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, TextBit>> predicate) where T: class
{
    var result = source.Include(predicate).ThenInclude(t => t.Translations);

    return result;
}
```

And tests proved successful.

Now, in some cases, I have entities that have all their texts in a child - for example `Article` entity has an `ArticleInfo` property that contains a few text elements. So I figure I just needed to do another extension that was a `ThenInclude` instead. With a few differences I finally get this :

```
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, ICollection<Translation>> ThenIncludeTextBitWithTranslations<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TextBit>(this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> source, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TextBit>> predicate) where TEntity: class
{
    var result = source.ThenInclude(predicate)
                       .ThenInclude(t => t.Translations);

    return result;
}
```

And now I get this error:

> 'TextBit' does not contain a definition for 'Translations' and no extension method 'Translations' accepting an argument of 'TextBit' type was found

This error appears on the last lambda expression `t => t.Translations`.

This error is extremely weird for me, I've been looking all over the internet for some help on the matter but I was unsuccessful.

I tried forcing the type to the `ThenInclude` by adding them manually :

```
var result = source.ThenInclude(predicate)
                   .ThenInclude<TEntity, TextBit, ICollection<Translation>>(t => t.Translations);
```

but without success.

Does anyone have some clues as to why?

I'm very much at a loss here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra type parameter `TextBit` in second one (`ThenIncludeTextBitWithTranslations<TEntity, TPreviousProperty, TextBit>`), so it is considered as a generic type, not an actual one, remove it:

```
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, ICollection<Translation>> ThenIncludeTextBitWithTranslations<TEntity, TPreviousProperty>(this IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TPreviousProperty> source, Expression<Func<TPreviousProperty, TextBit>> predicate) where TEntity: class
{
    var result = source.ThenInclude(predicate).ThenInclude(t => t.Translations);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: That was it... My god, I just copied the basic ThenInclude Structure and Replaced my thing with what I needed without realising that I Declared a new Generic type Hiding my Entity.... Still I feel like it should've told me that this new Generic type was hiding my Entity Type...
All this time I was nearly punching my screen ahah, Thanks a lot!